# JavaScript Event State Machine

Tags: javascript, state-machine

Does anybody know of any javascript implementations of a state machine? My goal is to setup a state machine implementation that would bind events to state transitions. So, if a user clicks on a button then the state will be changed, and this state might define certain values in objects to be changed for example.

I want this to be a state machine simply because there will be a rules json file that will allow to dictate what values change of various objects when certain events are called. Because this will be structured within the file, I think it would be easy to parse that information into a state machine object.

Comment: https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine could be that you're looking for.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two main libraries for a finite state machine in js :

1/ [Machina](https://github.com/ifandelse/machina.js):
Very well documented, examples, supports two JavaScript message bus providers out of the box: [postal.js](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js) and [amplify.js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js).

2/ [Javascript State Machine](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine):
simpler and easier to use, perfect for "basic" usages.

Answer (score 6):

I recently built a state machine implementation in JS, which is certainly the easiest to configure, thanks to its transition DSL:

```
transitions: [
  'next    : intro > form > finish',
  'back    : intro < form           < error',
  'error   :         form >           error',
  'restart : intro        < finish'
]
```

It's really flexible in both configuration and event handler assignment, you can add and remove states at runtime, pause and resume transitions, hook into a ton of events, with helpers for jQuery and reactive frameworks like Vue:

[image: state-machine-demo]

Docs and a whole host of demos here:

- http://statemachine.davestewart.io

Comment: A DSL for state machines certainly looks like an interesting idea 

Comment: X-State is probably the most popular state machine these days. At some point I'd like to refactor the DSL generator to work with this or X-State. But that may be a while!

Answer (score 4):

Little bit of promotion for my state machine: stateflow
I just created my own state machine because i found none which was simple enough for me.

a flow is defined with a js object where the property is the state name and the value is another js object with following properties.

- type: begin, end or state (default).
- action: function with a State instance object set to this, can also be named action previously registered or another flow definition in this case it is a subflow.
- on: property is to be matched event and value is the next state to goto

Simple example

```
var stateflow = require('stateflow');
var flow = new stateflow.StateFlow({
   a: {
       type:'begin',
       action: function(complete) {
           // do something
           complete('done');    
       },
       on: {
           done:'b',
           again:'a'
       }
   }, 
   b: {
       type:'end',
       action: function(complete) {
           complete('finished');
       }
   }
});
flow.start(function(event) {
   console.log('flow result:', event);
});
```

Check it out on git https://github.com/philipdev/stateflow or via npm

Comment: Thanks, any comments on how this can be added to AngularJS 1.x app?

Answer (score 3):

Try taking a look at https://github.com/steelbreeze/state.js - it supports much of the state machine semantics as described in the UML 2 spec while still being performant.
There's not much in the way of documentation yet, but the examples and tests should provide a good reference.

Comment: I have been using that library and I am very satisfied with it. We integrated it to our thingml approach (https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/ThingML)

Answer (score 2):

You'll find library designed with jQuery that seems to do what you're looking for and binding automatically the events for you:

- https://github.com/lucaong/jquery-machine (see example https://github.com/lucaong/jquery-machine/blob/master/examples/onoff.html)
- https://github.com/intersel/iFSM (see example https://github.com/intersel/iFSM/blob/master/Examples/Example_1.html)

Answer (score 1):

My pick on this with the js-fsm micro library.

**Features**

- State based FSM description. A state composed of a and an array of state transitions.
- Transition from events. Multiple events define ORed events.
- Transition from conditions. A condition is a key: value pair that should match on the condition object. Multiple key, value pairs defined ANDed conditions. Multiple conditions define ORed conditions
- Each transition can optionally call actions or multiple actions. Actions can optionally have arguments or be members of this.
- State machine could be mixed (as a mixin) to an existing object or a constructor's prototype. A method for this is provided.
- State machine can optionally log if a log method exists on this or is provided.
- AMD and Node modules are supported.
- Unit tests with QUnit.

[js-fsm github page.](https://github.com/basos9/js-fsm)

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would also talk about my own state machine library. I came to this SO question two years ago, and could not find anything that would fit my requirements, so I wrote [state-transducer](https://github.com/brucou/state-transducer).

The key objectives for the API was :

- functional API, entirely devoided of effect, with encapsulated internal state
- generality and reusability (there is no provision made to accommodate specific use cases or frameworks)
- it must be possible to add a concurrency and/or communication mechanism on top of the current design
- it must be possible to integrate smoothly into React, Angular and your popular framework

It is used to [modelize user interfaces](https://github.com/brucou/movie-search-app/blob/specs-all/article/article.md), turning user flows

[image: user flow]

into state machines

[image: fsm]

Answer (score 0):

You may find this library of use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mistic

Disclaimer: I maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

**[AsyncMachine](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/asyncmachine)** is another, less orthodox approach to state machine in JS (I'm the author). It's relational and supports multiple states being active simultaneously. Here's some code to answer your original question - after you click the button, there's side effects in terms of a new state and an attr on the context object:

```js
const {
  machine
} = asyncmachine
// define states & relations
const state = {
  Clicked: {
    add: ['ShowFooter']
  },
  ShowFooter: {}
}
const example = machine(state)
// define handlers
example.Clicked_state = function() {
  this.timeout = setTimeout(
    this.dropByListener('Clicked'), 3000)
}

function render() {
  console.log('render')
  // get all the active state as class names
  const classes = example.is().join(' ')
  console.log(classes)
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `
    <div class="${classes}">
      <button>CLICK</button>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  `
}
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener(
  'click', example.addByListener('Clicked'))
// bind render to any state change
example.on('tick', render)
render()
```

```css
.Clicked button {
  background: red;
}

footer {
  display: none;
}

.ShowFooter footer {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/asyncmachine@3.4.1/dist/asyncmachine.umd.js"></script>
<div id='content' />
```

There's also an inspector which can visualize the way your machine works (with time travel), eg:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used [xtstate](https://xstate.js.org/docs/), It address almost all the concerns posted in the question. It has a great [visualizer](https://xstate.js.org/viz/) try it out.